# jQuery - inserting a string inside a textarea, then selecting a portion of it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textarea

Like SO has for example the **B** button:

`**strong text**`

But `strong text` to be automatically selected, and the cursor to be positioned just before the `s`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use my [Rangy Inputs jQuery plug-in](http://code.google.com/p/rangyinputs) now that I've finally got round to documenting it. Using it, the following will do the job:

```
$textArea = $("#yourtextarea");
$textArea.focus();
$textArea.surroundSelectedText("**", "**");
```

This will select the same text as was selected before, which is what SO does. However, if you prefer to have a caret before the "s" as you say then you can add the following:

```
$textArea.collapseSelection(true);
```

jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/AL7uY/